# Phalcon Installation Error - Ubuntu

Tags: php, configuration, installation, ubuntu-12.04, phalcon

I tried installing Phalcon in Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.5. I have followed the same steps as in `http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-4-steps-install-custom-php-extensions-zend-server-7/`.

But after installation, I got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/phalcon.so' - /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: output_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

Can anyone guide me what went wrong with my installation?

Comment: Try to restart service with `sudo service php5-fpm restart`. Otherwise first option should be to follow [installation from official page](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#linux-solaris).

Answer (score 2):

This is looks more like that you have wrong order of loading modules, so phalcon trying to load some PHP module but it cannot because you've loading phalcon before functions beign loaded.

So simple when you're using for loading mods-enabled or conf-enabled, rename phalcon config file to 99-phalcon.conf to make it loaded as last.

**When this will not help you**

Then issue will be version of installed phalcon does not match machine architecture or version of PHP or threads of PHP. In that case is best of to install phalcon from official package or download actual phalcon from official websites. https://phalconphp.com/en/download

Answer (score 0):

In official [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#linux-solaris) described all necessary steps. You need just follow them step by step.
Your problem looks like you miss some dependency during installation...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the official documentation:

```
    $ curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repos..." | sudo bash

    $  sudo apt-get install php5.0-phalcon
```

Now in certain linux distros (eg linux mint), you may encounter errors because in the phalcon repository, they have versions for debian and ubuntu, not mint. But your linux will try to find a version for your distro (Mint in my casse). To fix it, you simply change linux version in the file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/phalcon_stable.list` 
For example,in my case, I replaced `"/mint/ tessa"` with `"/debian/ stretch"` . Watch the [video](https://youtu.be/Nbu0Ww4YpRI) if you are still confused.